# How to find names that contain a single “e” in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

My table name is `student` and column name is `FullName`.

Can anyone help with this question? I have tried:

```
select FullName from student where fullName like "e"
```

But this is returning 0 rows.

Answer (score 3):

If you want students that contain at leas one `'e'`, then:

```
select fullname 
from student 
where fullname like '%e%'
```

Note the use of the wildcard character (`%`) around the `e`, which searches for the character anywhere in the string.

But if you really mean students that contain *a single `e`* (not more, not less), then you need to filter out names that contain more than one. For this, you can do:

```
select fullname 
from student 
where fullname like '%e%' and fullname not like '%e%e%'
```

You could also use `replace()` and `char_length()`:

```
select fullname 
from student 
where char_length(replace(fullname, 'e', '')) = char_length(fullname) - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
select fullname
from student
where fullname regexp '^[^e]*e[^e]*$'
```